# Is there a way to prevent windows/nvidia drivers from seeing a resolution option?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-geforce

I have a pair of Auria monitors on my Windows 8.1 system that have panels with a maximum resolution of 2560 x 1440, but their hardware offers the option to receive signal at 2880 x 1620.

This normally isn't a problem, but I want to use the Dynamic Super Resolution feature on my graphics card (an Nvidia GTX 970), and this feature seems to force output to the monitor at 2880 x 1620 rather than 2560 x 1440.

Is there any way to prevent a resolution from showing up as an option in Windows or to force Nvidia Control Panel to use a lower resolution for Dynamic Super Resolution?